# Iterating through a Backbone.PageableCollection not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, underscore.js, backbone.paginator

I have a [Backbone.PageableCollection](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone-pageable) (`@customers`) whose models I would like to iterate through.  I have tried many things -- including what I thought was obvious:

```
@customers.each (customer) ->
  console.log customer
```

Unfortunately, this logs out something that looks like a collection but has no model data in it.  I know that the collection has been fully synced, because when I log out `@customers.models` I can see an array of model data:

[image]

Strangely, if I do this:

```
_.each @customers.models, (customer) ->
  console.log customer
```

I get the same, unhelpful result as above.

What am I missing?

**Update:**

Looking closer at the object logged by `console.log customer` in both approaches, this looks like a model with unpopulated attributes.  This is strange since logging `@customers.models` shows an array of models with attributes fully populated.  In addition, the `each` loop only executes once.

**Update 2:**

I tried the following per agconti's suggestion below:

```
@customers.each (@customers, c) ->
  console.log @customers, c
```

which compiles to:

```
      return this.customers.each((function(_this) {
        return function(customers, c) {
          _this.customers = customers;
          return console.log(_this.customer, c);
        };
      })(this));
```

and logs `undefined` and a `0`.

**Update 3:**

If I set:

```
window.customers = @customers
```

and then enter this into the console:

```
_.each(customers.models, function (customer) { return console.log(customer)});
```

I get a log of all the customer models.  I'm really confused now...

**Update 4:**

I've narrowed this down to a timing issue.  I run this code after the collection has synced, but it seems that model parsing in the collection happens later.

Comment: what is the returned when you log `@customers`?

Comment: I updated update 2 also.  This syntax makes no sense to me though.  I still would expect `@customers.each (customer) -> console.log customer` to work.

Comment: Thats the problem. if `this.customers` is undefined then `.each()` cannot iterate through it. Try creating a test collection and test iterating through that, and then track down why customers inst defined. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: The syntax you suggested is clobbering `@customers` which is why it is logging `undefined`.  I log out `@customers` right before the `each` clause and it is fully defined.  The mystery is why logging `@customers.models[0]` logs an unpopulated model and why the `each` loop iterates only once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an iterator for `.each()`. Do this instead:

```
@customers.each (@customers, c) ->
  console.log c
```

If you check the backbone docs on [`.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) you see that it takes in three properties; `(list, iterator, [context])`. Since you're just logging customer  and not an iterator of the customer collection it just logs the entire collection.

Comment: That sounds like a good point that I will try shortly, but the backbone documentation does not mention an iterator.  It shows:

books.each(function(book) {
  book.publish();
});

Comment: @Erik I'm not familiar with the paginator plugin so let me know if it works out :)

Comment: No joy.  `console.log c` logs 0.  There are 52 customers and this only happens once.

Comment: @Erik did you try it the underscore way with `_.each (customer, c) ->`?

Comment: Same result when I do it the underscore way.

Comment: @Erik what does your coffeescript build to? I dont think the each method is getting the function it expects. it should be `this.customers.each(function(this.customer, c){console.log(c);});`

Comment: @Erik Also! We both for got to specify the list correctly as the collection `@customers`. try that and let me know if it works. I updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

A backbone collection's models are stored at `Collection.models`, thats what you need to iterate over. 
when doing
    `_.each @customers`, you are iterating over the collection object's attributes, not its models
so what you want is
`_.each @customers.models, (customer) -> console.log customer`

Comment: Yep, which is what I am doing i the second code example.  The backbone docs also say that `@customers.each (customer) -> console.log customer` should work too -- which is what I have tried in the first code sample.

Comment: oops, sorry i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This has turned out to be some problem in my fetching/syncing code.  This code is not supposed to run until the customers collection is fully synced, but something (as yet undetermined) is allowing it to run before the collection is fully synced.